# Is there a way to solve OS Error in Django Project

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I started learning Django recently.
I first ran the virtual enviroment, then installed Django and then `python manage.py runserver`but im recieving this error:

```
    Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate  
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 618, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 603, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 318, in run   
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 324, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 364, in tick  
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 380, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 278, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\123\Downloads\django-react-boilerplate-master\django-react-boilerplate-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1204, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 200, in resolve
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

I downloaded this https://github.com/justdjango/django-react-boilerplate project and was trying to run this in the terminal.
If someone can help please. Thankyou.

Comment: did you run makemigrations command? try to "pip install django-allauth"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your setup. After activating your environment, run this command;

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

As you downloaded the code from the mentioned link, that also has a file, requirements.txt which shows all the modules required to make the project run and the above command will install all of them at once.
After that run;

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then you will be ready;

```
python manage.py ruunserver
```